# Object has type qualifiers that are not compatible with the member function

Tags: c++, types, constants, compatibility, qualifiers

My class `Game` has a member `EntityManager entityManager_`.

The class `EntityManager` has a private member `Player player_` and the public getter function `Player &EntityManager::getPlayer()` which returns `player_`.

The class `Player` has for example the functions `void startMoving()` and `sf::Vector2f getPosition() const`.

Now, I can without problems call `entityManager_.getPlayer().startMoving();` from within my `Game` class, but when I try for example the following code to get the player's position:

`sf::Vector2f playerPosition = entityManager_.getPlayer().getPosition();`

I get the following error:

IntelliSense:

```
EntityManager Game::entityManager_

Error: the object has type qualifiers that are not compatible with the member function

object type is: const EntityManager
```

Output:

```
game.cpp(261): error C2662: 'EntityManager::getPlayer' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const EntityManager' to 'EntityManager &'
          Conversion loses qualifiers
```

I tried removing the `const` from the player's getPosition function but nothing changed.

I know it probably has something to do with the `const` but I can't figure out what to change! Could someone please help me?

Comment: I suspect you don't have a const version of getPlayer but you have not shown any code.

Comment: Adding `const` to `getPlayer` removes the error, but could you tell me what I have to return then instead of `player_`? Because now `getPlayer` tells me: error: qualifiers dropped in reference of type "Player &" to initializer of type "const Player"

Comment: @A.D.: Are you inside a member function that is itself declared `const`?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Ah, yes. That member function is indeed `const`. I removed it and now it's working! Thank you

Comment: You need `Player &EntityManager::getPlayer() { return _player; }` AND `const Player &EntityManager::getPlayer() const { return _player; }`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The error message is quite explicit:

```
game.cpp(261): error C2662: 'EntityManager::getPlayer' : 
               cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const EntityManager' to 
                                                  'EntityManager &'
          Conversion loses qualifiers
```

In the context where you are calling `getPlayer` the object/reference is `const`. You cannot call a non-const member function on a `const` object or through a `const` reference or pointer to `const`.

Because the error refers to `this`, the most likely reason is that this code is inside a member function that is `const`.